# PhotoKit: How to remove source media file when user delete asset in Photos.app?

Tags: ios, swift, photo, phasset, photokit

I have a problem with PhotoKit:
In my app, i get a mp4 video from remote camera and save it to phone filesystem in documents folder. 
After this, I create an asset by using `PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL:)` and add it to custom assetCollection. After that, I can see this video in Photos.app and I can delete it by tapping trash button. But if I delete it from Photos.app list, it won't be displayed in list but original source file won't be removed from phone memory.

I want source file to be removed when user delete asset. How can I do this? Any ideas?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: I assume you are using iOS 8+ bc of `PHAssetChangeRequest`... recent versions of Photos.app have added a "Recently Deleted" folder. (I can't find documentation on that change, maybe the app was rolled with the API...) but if you are using *only* trash button, you should check to see if it is really deleted.

Comment: @benc thanks for clarification, but this didn't help. No matter, even f I force-delete video from "Recently Deleted" --- file remains in memory :(

Comment: Yeah, I'm about to start using PhotoKit (survived just `UIImagePicker`...) but I did a quick skim of the docs and couldn't find an explanation.